# Explaination of the follwing query , `the AND Id NOT IN` part

Tags: apex, trigger

```
[SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New AND Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)]
```

Comment: It only returns all the accounts which were updated/inserted or deleted in the trigger without those who are linked to any opportunity in the database.

Comment: @MartinLezer Please do not answer questions in comments.

Comment: @Vishal Sharma, what part of the query dont you understand? have you read the [SOQL and SOSL Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm) ?

Comment: I think you'd find the query would likely be easier to understand if read in context of the code that surrounds it. It's obviously from a trigger. It's not a "stand alone" query that you'd execute via anonymous apex.

Comment: @glls i am in between
`AND Id NOT IN` was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query finds all accounts in the current trigger execution context (`Id IN :Trigger.new`) that do not have an opportunity (`Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)`).